# Connecting to Django via RestKit (iOS) and TastyPie

Tags: ios, django, nsurlconnection, restkit, tastypie

Good morning everyone,

So we decided to create an iOS app and to do so, we added a REST Web-Service with TastyPie to our app. Everything is great so far... but we have a small problem.

On the iOS side, we are using RestKit and we are faced with the authentication problem. We can make the user login, but Django needs to return something back to the iOS App in order to retain the session and access the rest of the possible API after the user has logged in.

On the web side, we are using Django Sessions and Cookies. Should we just send back the session and store it in the HTTP header in iOS? OR, I have seen that we could use the ApiKeyAuthentication. Does that mean the HTTP Header would always have the ApiKey in its header, as well as the username? Is that even safe?

I am kind of confused, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Is that really necessary? I really need the user to enter his/her username/password. Think of it has when you login in the Facebook app on the iPhone. They establish a link with their servers to get the data afterwards...

Comment: You would definitely want to use OAuth2 for authentication. The work flow would go like this. User opens app, app checks for auth token. It doesn't exist. User is take to your login screen most likely with a web view. They log in and are taken to a page that says "do you want the app to be able to access your account", user clicks authorize. Django app responds with a response then iOS app takes the response and makes another request to django, django then returns an auth token. Your app stores that auth token in core memory and uses it to make requests to API end points.